# Issue passing a reference to another class within a class

Tags: c++, arduino

I have created the following class which has an object being passed in by reference and is implemented the following way.

```
Diablo_Serial_4DLib Display(&DisplaySerial);

ZenDisplay ui(Display);
```

```
class ZenDisplay
{
  public:
    ZenDisplay(Diablo_Serial_4DLib &display);
    void setup();
  private:
    Diablo_Serial_4DLib* _display;
};
```

The constructor is straight forward and works as expected, no problem so far.

```
// Constructor /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
ZenDisplay::ZenDisplay(Diablo_Serial_4DLib &display)
{
    _display = &display;
}
```

I want to instantiate ZenSpeakerGroup class and pass in the same reference into it's constructor

```
class ZenSpeakerGroup
{
  public:
    ZenSpeakerGroup(Diablo_Serial_4DLib &display);
  private:
    Diablo_Serial_4DLib* _display;
};
```

```
ZenSpeakerGroup::ZenSpeakerGroup(Diablo_Serial_4DLib &display)
{
    _display = &display;
}
```

I have modified the original working class to the following

```
class ZenDisplay
{
  public:
    ZenDisplay(Diablo_Serial_4DLib &display);
    void setup();
  private:
    Diablo_Serial_4DLib* _display;
    ZenSpeakerGroup _speakerGroup;
};
```

```
// Constructor /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
ZenDisplay::ZenDisplay(Diablo_Serial_4DLib &display) : _speakerGroup(&display)
{
    _display = &display;
}
```

Now I get the following error and not 100% sure what I am doing wrong.

```
Arduino: 1.8.16 (Mac OS X), Board: "DOIT ESP32 DEVKIT V1, 80MHz, 921600, None"

/Users/xxx/Documents/Arduino/libraries/ZenOne/ZenDisplay.cpp: In constructor 'ZenDisplay::ZenDisplay(Diablo_Serial_4DLib&)':
/Users/xxx/Documents/Arduino/libraries/ZenOne/ZenDisplay.cpp:14:78: error: no matching function for call to 'ZenSpeakerGroup::ZenSpeakerGroup(Diablo_Serial_4DLib*)'
 ZenDisplay::ZenDisplay(Diablo_Serial_4DLib &display) : _speakerGroup(&display)
                                                                              ^
In file included from /Users/xxx/Documents/Arduino/libraries/ZenOne/ZenDisplay.h:14,
                 from /Users/xxx/Documents/Arduino/libraries/ZenOne/ZenDisplay.cpp:9:
/Users/xxx/Documents/Arduino/libraries/ZenOne/ZenSpeakerGroup.h:18:5: note: candidate: 'ZenSpeakerGroup::ZenSpeakerGroup(Diablo_Serial_4DLib&)'
     ZenSpeakerGroup(Diablo_Serial_4DLib &display);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/xxx/Documents/Arduino/libraries/ZenOne/ZenSpeakerGroup.h:18:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Diablo_Serial_4DLib*' to 'Diablo_Serial_4DLib&'
/Users/xxx/Documents/Arduino/libraries/ZenOne/ZenSpeakerGroup.h:15:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr ZenSpeakerGroup::ZenSpeakerGroup(const ZenSpeakerGroup&)'
 class ZenSpeakerGroup
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/xxx/Documents/Arduino/libraries/ZenOne/ZenSpeakerGroup.h:15:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Diablo_Serial_4DLib*' to 'const ZenSpeakerGroup&'
/Users/xxx/Documents/Arduino/libraries/ZenOne/ZenSpeakerGroup.h:15:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr ZenSpeakerGroup::ZenSpeakerGroup(ZenSpeakerGroup&&)'
/Users/xxx/Documents/Arduino/libraries/ZenOne/ZenSpeakerGroup.h:15:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Diablo_Serial_4DLib*' to 'ZenSpeakerGroup&&'
exit status 1
Error compiling for board DOIT ESP32 DEVKIT V1.


This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

I also tried the following with no success.
`_speakerGroup = new ZenSpeakerGroup(&display)`
I would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: `ZenSpeakerGroup::ZenSpeakerGroup` takes a reference, not a pointer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this.  I am passing the same &display reference to ZenDisplay and ZenSpeakerGroup.  Can you elaborate on what you think would solve the issue?

Comment: Please review [ask]. Good questions start with the question; they don't make people scroll just to find out what your question is about, much less what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way of passing the display reference to ZenSpeakerGroup

```
ZenDisplay::ZenDisplay(Diablo_Serial_4DLib &display) : _speakerGroup(display)
{
    _display = &display;
}
```

Comment: What changed? Why is this way correct? This is not much better than a code-only answer (but at least the text does describe which part of the code changed).

Comment: The change was from _speakerGroup(&display) to _speakerGroup(display)

Comment: Information in the comments is subject to disappear at any time. If you do not edit the information into your answer, it might as well not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I have made this mistake aswell it's a typo

make sure when you want to intialize a reference define it as a refference

```
class ZenDisplay{
 public:
  ZenDisplay(Diablo_Serial_4DLib &display);
  void setup();
 private:
  Diablo_Serial_4DLib& _display; // <--make sure this is a refference
 };
```

now initialize the refference

```
ZenDisplay::ZenDisplay(Diablo_Serial_4DLib &display){
  _display = display;
}
```